# Kotlin : Unresolved reference: alpha

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build

I don't understand why, on a project that use Java and Kotlin, in Kotlin I have issues calling some methods of the View class.

If I try to modify the alpha of my AppCompatButton

```
binding.button.alpha = 0.5F
```

of if I directly try to modify the alpha on a newly created View

```
val view = View(context)
view.alpha = 1F
```

I have the following error

Execution failed for task ':app:compileAllDebugKotlin'.
Unresolved reference: alpha

Some methods of the View class works some don't.

Comment: Never mind. I was having trouble finding that property in the docs on my phone. Not sure why OP has unresolved reference then.

Comment: Have you already tried forcing gradle build?

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange, because `View` class has the `alpha` property and it should work.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getAlpha()
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setAlpha(float)

Make sure that you have [API level](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#ApiLevels) >= 11 and that you have a correct imports:

```kotlin
import android.view.View
```

Comment: Indeed, I do have the import and I have The API lvl 21.

Comment: @ATHa, try cleaning the caches and restarting the AS.

Comment: Indeed, I do have the import and I have The API lvl 21.

Some methods from the view class does work like visibility
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getVisibility()

It seems like every added methods added after API 11 don't work on my project using Kotlin, they do work using Java, it's so weird...

Comment: I've already tried to clean the caches and restart AS.